# Stick them through the backseat

Tags: word-usage

A couple bought furniture for their new house they've just moved into.

> We'll lay the seats down and then stick them (furniture) through the backseat.

Can "in" be included here?

> We'll lay the seats down and then stick them **in** through the backseat.

And can it be:

> We'll lay the seats down and then put them **in** through the backseat.

And can it be "through the back" instead of "through the backseat"?

Comment: Where I come from, 'back seat' is two words, and it means what you sit on. You can't put anything "through" the back seat of a car without damaging it. Maybe you mean the **back seat area**?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Many modern sedans have a back seat section that folds down, allowing items to pass through it.

Comment: If you're using "through," then you reference what the furniture is actually going through: "through the rear door" or "through the hatchback door."

Comment: @Peter I have frequently loaded my car in that way, but I don't think of it as 'through the back seat', just 'loading the boot with the back seats down'.

Comment: @KateBunting, in my car there is a central seat rest and when that is down you can get a thin object through the gap between the seats. The seat back cushion is continuous above and below, so it is an actual hole in the seat.

Comment: Pretty clearly the OP's question is about the use of "in" with certain verbs, and not about the name for that part of a car. Let's keep our responses helpful to the OP

Answer (score 1):

*Stick them in through the back seat* implies the item has passed into (or mostly into) the car through the seat. *Stick them through* does not suggest it has gone all the way; it might have or there might only be a small part going through the seat. Either might work for garden stakes, but probably not for furniture. If the seats are folded down, nothing will go through them anyway. *Stick them in through the back* would be better.

Comment: So does "backseat" or "back" sound better?

Comment: And I thought this  whole "seats folding-down" thing was pretty normal, and not confusing at all.

Comment: They're both fine, but nobody on ell.stackexchange will argue with you if you say "back"

Answer (score -1):

Yes, all these are correct. My own roommate said "through the back seat" earlier today before I'd even read this question.

Comment: If you downvote, please comment